# Where can I download the production files for Big Buck Bunny?

Tags: blend-files

I would like to download the production files for Big Buck Bunny (one of the most famous movies created with Blender) but I am having difficulty finding the files.

[This page](https://peach.blender.org/download/) on the Blender website contains a link to [a .torrent file](http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_production.torrent) titled "Production Repository from DVD". However, the tracker is offline. The page also includes an "Entire Studio Backup", but the website hosting it (http://blender-mirror.kino3d.org/) is offline.

The Web Archive only seems to have a copy of the video, not the production files. [This website](http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/explore.html) offers some files but none of them seem to include the models for the characters or the textures.

Where can I find these files?

Comment: https://cloud.blender.org/

Comment: @lbalazscs the files available for download there require a subscription.

Comment: Yes, this stuff is not supposed to be free as in free beer. Blender Institute also needs money.

Comment: @lbalazscs yes, but these files were obviously available for free at some point.

Comment: @lbalazscs the files are still creative commons, open for everyone, and freely available. The subscriptions is just a revenue model, nothing stops anyone from redistributing the files freely, although apparently no one does anymore out of respect for the Blender foundation

Comment: Interestingly the torrent worked for me.